# Install mod_wsgi with Python 2.7 on Windows 64 bit

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Django website, which is written using Python 2.7, on a windows 64 bit machine (Windows Server 2008 R2). I installed the pre-compiled version of Apache (Apache 2.4.16 x64) from https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx (due to lack of option provided by Apache Lounge***), and have checked that Python 2.7 runs on 64 bit and compiles with VC9. I wasn't able to find a pre-built binary for mod_wsgi (for Windows 64 bit and compiled with VC9), so I downloaded the source code for mod_wsgi from https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases/tag/4.4.13 and followed the direction from https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst, changing the `ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk` file to point at the right directories for `APACHE_ROOTDIR` and `PYTHON_ROOTDIR`, and using C++ 2008 64-bit Command Prompt to run the command `nmake -f ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk clean`. However, this gave me the error:

```
wsgi_memory.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol GetProcessMemoryInfo referenced
  in function getPeakRSS
mod_wsgi.so : fatal error LINK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: `"...\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\c1.EXE"` :
  return code `0x2`
Stop.
```

I have read the installation and configuration documents for mod_wsgi multiple times and have searched the web including SO for the past few hours to no avail. What am I doing wrong here and how could I fix it?

***I know the official document for installing mod_wsgi warns against using binaries from other sources than Apache Lounge but I don't seem to be able to find the right compiled version (for VC9 and Windows 64 bit) from the site. Could this be a problem and if so, how could I fix it?

**Update**: following Adelin's suggestion, I was able to get `namke -f ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk clean` to run. However, when I try running `namke -f ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk` or `namke -f ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk install`, I get pages of warnings that say: `warning C4820: '...' : '...' bytes padding added after data member '...'` until the compiler quits with

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory
...\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_memory.c<124> : warning C4711: function 'getCurrentRSS' selected for automatic inline expansion
NMAKE: fatal error U1077: '"C:\...\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\c1.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be and how I should go about fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same error.

The problem is that the `cl.exe` doesn't find the `psapi.lib`. This lib  includes the function referenced in `wsgi_memory.c` - `GetProcessMemoryInfo`.

To fix this, you should follow these steps:

1. Locate `psapi.lib` (run a search on `C:\`)
2. Open the `ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk` file you are using to compile, with
   any text editor
3. See what other `.mk` file it includes. Most probably `common-VC9.mk`
4. Open that file (`common-VC9.mk`) with any text editor
5. Under `LDFLAGS`, append yet another line of `/LIBPATH:"PATH_FOUND_AT_STEP_1"\`
6. Save changes and retry

What a pain in the ass this was for me too :)

P.S. If you don't find `psapi.lib` anywhere, it's because you don't have the Windows SDK. I installed both [Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and [Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) SDKs and eventually had the `psapi.lib` located here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64`

**Edit:**
To give you a solution for your newest errors in a somewhat general way, whenever `nmake` throws `"No such file"` errors, the location for the file is not properly referenced in `common-VC9.mk` file.

There are two types of files `nmake` will look for: `.h` or `.lib`.

If a `.h` is not found, the corresponding path should be properly referenced under the `CPPFLAGS` variable of `common-VC9.mk` file. 
If a `.lib` is not found, you need to update `LDFLAGS` path accordingly.

How? The same way you included the path for `psapi.lib`: locate the file and append the corresponding path to the proper variable: `CPPFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get ```nmake ... clean``` to run with your suggestion, but now the compiler is throwing me errors when I try running ```nmake ...``` and ```nmake ... install```. I've updated the question to reflect these new errors - do you have any insight regarding this problem?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What would be the equivalent of ```LIBPATH``` to a ```.h``` file when I add the path to ```python.h``` in ```CPPFLAGS```?

Comment: Exclusively for `python.h` and since i see you have Python 2.7, it should be a new line of `/I"C:\Python27\include"\` (assuming you have python installed in that directory.