# while doing pip install mod_wsgi is failing

Tags: python, django, visual-c++, pip, mod-wsgi

I am trying to put my django site on apache and i am following these tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6-yJpPEpoE)
In doing these by these command

```
set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:\xampp\apache
pip install mod_wsgi
```

I am getting these error.

```
wsgi_apache.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_conv_utf8_to_ucs2
wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_shared_make
wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_shared_copy
wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_free
wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_alloc
wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_shared_destroy
wsgi_buckets.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_bucket_shared_split
wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_show_mpm
wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_server_description
wsgi_interp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_server_built
wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_scoreboard_process
wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_get_scoreboard_worker_from_indexes
wsgi_metrics.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_exists_scoreboard_image
wsgi_thread.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_threadkey_private_get
wsgi_thread.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_threadkey_private_set
build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\mod_wsgi\server\mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 101 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I had already tried other lot answers available on stackoverflow but nothing works.Every help will be appreciated

Comment: Isn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32904265/3233388) covering this scenario? You're probably missing some SDK , or it's not in the default location and you need to point to it

Comment: @Adelin no because that is for python.h and he had tried different thing

Comment: It's the exact same principle. `unresolved externals` == `missing SDK`. So, if you have the SDK, it needs to be pointed to correctly.

Comment: No i does not have any sdk i am just doing pip install mod_wsgi .

Comment: I am using python 3.6 and anaconda

Comment: This is usually because you are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit binaries. Ensure you are using 64 bit versions of Python, MS C/C++ compilers and runtime, and Apache.

Answer (score 0):

As [graham-dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton) said in the comments, you must have the same version (x86) python, MS build tools, and Apache. Or x64.